# jQuery: Select a <p> tag within a <li>

Tags: jquery, this, parent-child

I'm trying to use jquery to fade out a `<p>` tag within a `<li>` when a delete button is selected.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Here is some text!</p>
        <span class="delete">Delete</span>
    <li>
<ul>
```

Here is my jQuery so far:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $("p").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your structure as quoted, simply:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $(this).prev("p").fadeOut(); 
});
```

If it's possible the `p` won't be the *immediate* predecessor to the delete link, then you can do this:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $(this).closest("li").find("p").fadeOut(); 
});
```

...which will fade out *all* `p` elements it finds in the `li`, or this:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $(this).closest("li").find("p").first().fadeOut(); 
});
```

...which will fade out the *first* `p` element it finds in the `li`, or this:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $(this).prevAll("p").first().fadeOut(); 
});
```

...which will fade out the first sibling it finds working backward from the delete link.

References:

- [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) - find the *immediate* previous sibling, or nothing if it doesn't match the selector
- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - find the nearest ancestor matching a selector
- [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - find all descendants matching a selector
- [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) - find all previous siblings matching a selector, in reverse document order (e.g., working backward from the current element)
- [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) - only grab the first element in the current set

Comment: `$(this).closest("li").find("p").first.fadeOut();` missing '()' in .first() ? or? :)

Comment: @roXon: Thanks, fixed. That makes *two* errors in that one line of code so far. ;-) \*sigh\*

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $(this).closest("li").find("p").fadeOut(); 
});
```

…or you use `parent()` instead of `closest()`.

If the `<p>` *always* precedes the `<span>`, you can also do:

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    //Needs to select the <p> tag within the same <li> 
    $(this).prev("p").fadeOut(); 
});
```